# On-demand Permissions in static region

Tags: android

The latest Android 6.0 [forces developers](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to check and request permissions on-demand, and use support libraries to do so in previous versions via calls such as:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(someAndroidContext, somePermission)
```

However, I have a special case where I require file i/o permissions prior to the existence of any `Context` due to native library extraction and loading that must happen during a class's `static` initialization before the Context comes into being. Adding the permissions to the manifest isn't working (app is broken on brand new phones w/Android >= 6.0).

*Please try not to suggest workarounds such as "don't extract libraries" or ask for too much detail on the requirements, etc. as I may not be at liberty to discuss those details, the project is large and there are mutually-dependent libs that must both be in a non-packaged space prior to loading, and there are also 3rd-party libs that are very complex projects themselves (one has 20+ dependencies that have been carefully optimized and built by hand for specific architectures per client request).*

TL;DR **Is there a way to "pre-ask" for permissions prior to our app launch, or request permission w/o a `Context`?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to "pre-ask" for permissions prior to our app launch

Keep your `targetSdkVersion` below 23 until the end of time, pray that Google doesn't change the rules, and pray that you do not come up with a competing reason to raise `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher. With a `targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower, your permissions are granted at install time (as is the case on Android 5.1 and below).

Otherwise, no.

Also note that you still might not be able to write to external storage, even with the pre-granted permission. The user is welcome to install your app, go into Settings, revoke the storage permissions, then run your app.

> request permission w/o a Context?

No. Requesting permissions comes in the form of starting a system-supplied activity, and that requires a `Context`.

> I have a special case where I require file i/o permissions prior to the existence of any Context due to native library extraction and loading that must happen during a class's static initialization before the Context comes into being

You do not need "file i/o permissions" for [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Extracting libraries to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is stupid beyond words, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: The errors happen w/external storage, as that is where developer config files that override the packaged versions reside for very non-stupid reasons (custom OS that has no writable internal storage). Extraction happens both internally and/or externally depending on config. External extraction is very important for testing and verification purposes for developers who cannot access the device directly. That stuff is out of my hands.

Comment: @EntangledLoops: "custom OS that has no writable internal storage" -- then you can also change the OS to address your original problem regarding permissions.

Comment: No I can't, as it's built by a 3rd-party client that is a large company who makes the OS.

Comment: Anyways, the test process is in use w/far more people than myself, so I can't just go changing that. As I wrote above, a workaround won't due. I'm testing your `targetSdk` change now.